# como restar 2 campos en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Mi problema es el siguiente quiero restar los siguientes campos:

`TOTAL DEBITO` - `TOTAL CREDITO`

Y el resultado ponerlo en otra columna llamarla `DIFERENCIA`

Tengo la query donde me muestra el código de cuenta, otra columna con el total de débito, otra columna con el total de crédito, acá vendría la columna `DIFERENCIA`

Estuve probando con diferentes cosas pero no pude hacerlo ¿Alguna idea o orientación?

Dejo mi query:

```
select tp.CodigoCuenta,

(
select SUM(MontoNeto) from Mayorizacion3 sub where sub.CodigoCuenta =  tp.CodigoCuenta and Id_movimiento = 1
) as TotalDebito,

(
select SUM(MontoNeto) from Mayorizacion3 sub where sub.CodigoCuenta =  tp.CodigoCuenta and Id_movimiento = 2
) as TotalCredito 

from Mayorizacion3 tp

group by tp.CodigoCuenta

order by tp.CodigoCuenta
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entiendo que lo puedes resolver de forma más sencilla usando la suma condicional:

```
select CodigoCuenta,
       SUM(case when Id_movimiento = 1 then MontoNeto else 0 end) as 'DEBITOS',
       SUM(case when Id_movimiento = 2 then MontoNeto else 0 end) as 'CREDITOS',
       SUM(case when Id_movimiento = 2 then MontoNeto * -1 else MontoNeto end) AS 'DIFERENCIA' 
       from Mayorizacion3 
       group by CodigoCuenta
```

Simplemente con una sola consulta a la tabla y condicionando el `SUM()` podemos calcular las tres columnas que buscas.